# What is best way to iterate embedded loops Iterative or Functional way?

Tags: java, functional-programming, apache-poi, guava

I was looking at some examples using Guava to iterate embedded loops to analyze what fits better in this case.

Our environment uses java 6 and we need to create a excel parser using Apache POI.

Found this example with two embedded for loops:

```
FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\test.xls"));

//Get the workbook instance for XLS file 
HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(file);

//Get first sheet from the workbook
HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

//Iterate through each rows from first sheet
for (Row row : sheet) {

    //For each row, iterate through each columns
    for (Cell cell : row) {

        switch(cell.getCellType()) {
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                System.out.print(cell.getBooleanCellValue() + "\t\t");
                break;
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue() + "\t\t");
                break;
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue() + "\t\t");
                break;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("");
}

file.close();
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("C:\\test.xls"));
workbook.write(out);
out.close();
```

I'd like to ask you what is the best way to iterate this, using while/for loops or guava filters? By the way, also found guava FluentIterable that may fit but I'm not so familiar with functional approaches.

Can you give me a hand? Thanks in advance

Comment: This isn't going to be simpler with functional approaches.  You could simplify it with for-each loops, though.

Comment: @LouisWasserman yes I know, I chose that example since found it done. I want to know the functional implementation instead the iterative using for/while

Comment: There isn't really one, with Guava.  Guava deals with functions, it doesn't have an interface for consumers that take an object and perform a side effect without returning anything.

Comment: @LouisWasserman and with another framework like lambdaj or lambda expressions in java 8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you *really* want to play with a functional approach to solving this problem, you could implement a functor for `Iterator`, and map a function that formats a cell type over your `rowIterator`.

*Unary function interface:*

```
public interface Fn1<A,B> {
  B apply(A a);
}
```

*A functor for `Iterator`:*

```
public class IteratorFunctor<A> {

  public final Iterator<A> i;

  private IteratorFunctor(Iterator<A> _i) {
    i = _i;
  }

  public <B> IteratorFunctor<B> map(Fn1<A,B> f) {
    List<B> bs = new LinkedList<B>();
    while (i.hasNext()) {
      bs.add(f.apply(i.next()));
    }
    return apply(bs.iterator());
  }

  public static <A> IteratorFunctor<A> apply(Iterator<A> _i) {
    return new IteratorFunctor<A>(_i);
  }

}
```

*A format function (for you, this would take a `Cell` and return perhaps a `String`):*

```
public static String format(int x) {
  switch (x) {
    case 1:
      return "one";
    case 2:
      return "two";
    default:
      return "big";
  }
}
```

*Demo:*

```
Fn1<Integer,String> formatFn = new Fn1<Integer,String>() {
  public String apply(Integer x) {
    return format(x);
  }
};

List<Integer> xs = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4);
IteratorFunctor<Integer> fi = IteratorFunctor.apply(xs.iterator());
IteratorFunctor<String> fs = fi.map(formatFn);
Iterator<String> ss = fs.i;

int i = 0;
while (ss.hasNext()) {
  System.out.println(i + ": " + ss.next());
  i = i + 1;
}

// Prints the following to stdout:
//
// 0: one
// 1: two
// 2: big
// 3: big
//
```

Comment: Thanks James for you detailed answer, definitely is a pain to do a functional approach over this kind of problem. I'll update the code to avoid iterators. So, isn't functional approach add clear code?

Comment: Strictly speaking this isn't quite a functional approach, since an `IteratorFunctor` changes its own state when you use `next()` on the underlying `Iterator` by calling `map`.  A better way would be to use something that doesn't change when you iterate over it (e.g. an array, a `List`, etc.).

Comment: Thanks again. James can you recommend me a documentation to learn more about functional in java?

Comment: No problem.  [Wampler's book](http://www.amazon.com/Functional-Programming-Java-Developers-Concurrency/dp/1449311032) is a great starting point.  After that, see what kinds of functional data structures and libraries other people are talking about (monads, applicative functors, etc.) and try to (1) implement them in Java and (2) use them in real code.

Comment: Thanks James, you rock